iTextSharp: Issues with flattened annotations
I am running into an issue where I need to merge multiple pdfs together and force them all to have a letter page size. The annotations are dropping off when resizing the page, so I thought I could flatten the pdf before resizing. But using the code below the flattened annotations are in the wrong spot and stretched all the way across the page. Is there something I'm overlooking here?
private List<byte[]> FlattenPdfFormToBytes(List<byte[]> pdfs)
{
    List<byte[]> outputImages = new List<byte[]>();

    if (pdfs == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    foreach (byte[] pdf in pdfs)
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(pdf), memStream)
        {
            FormFlattening = true,
            FreeTextFlattening = true
        };

        stamper.Close();
        outputImages.Add(memStream.ToArray());
    }

    return outputImages;
}

I was expecting the flattened annotations to stay in the correct spot and remain the correct size. But with this code the annotations are in the wrong spot and stretched across the page.

You use the PdfStamper class which is not part of iText 7 and newer anymore. Nonetheless you tagged your question [Tag:iText7]. Please clarify which text version you actually want to work with.

iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core, 1.7.5

Ah, that is a fork of the iTextSharp version 4.2 with some changes. I'd assume you observe bugs which may (or may not) have meanwhile been fixed. Can you share an example PDF illustrating the issue?

https://files.fm/u/x4pjmqeg8z

The before file shows the pdf with normal annotations.  The after shows the pdf attached to a letter, but the annotations are corrupted somehow

In pdfs annotations are stored in a rectangle object on the pdf file, not the page.  They do not auto scale when you change the page scale.  You need to find these in your pdf file and scale them with your page size adjustment.  I would recommend doing  % scaling, if possible, so you can apply it to page and annotations consistently.

I am now using iText7 instead of iTextSharp and am able to get the results that I require.  No need to delve into this issue any further. Thanks for your help
